# Best method to attach files to custom object in portal

Tags: customer-portal, attachment

I have a customer portal in my SF where users can make orders, how this is setup is by having a custom object with called Service_Orders which allows them to create their requests. I then have my apex class which on insert will copy all that data into selected fields in my SFDC Opportunity recordset.

This solution has worked fine for a number of years now, however I now need a way for users to upload attachments within the form, I wanted to know would copying the same method  of duplicating the data from Service_Orders to Opportunities be the best way? Or as the Opportunity is created when the Service Order is can I simply upload straight into the Opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the same method as before since your customers won't have access to Opportunity from a Customer Portal. Instead, you'll need to use a mirror object to save them to first, then use a trigger or class to copy the uploaded objects into Opportunity.

Comment: Looking at my options, would it be easier to implement an exact mirror or attachments to attchments between objects or would attachments -> to opportunity chatter feed be a better option?

Comment: Would need to see your schema to really answer that, but a direct mirror would seem to minimize the number of triggers/classes involved.